# css background for div not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to use an image as background for a div element. 

I've changed the `background-position` and `background-size` properties as well. But it's still not working. 
Below is the code:

```css
.large-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-5em;
   margin-top:-5em;
}

#center {
 background: url("img/newHex.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-menu">
 <div class="large-circle" id="center">
  <div class="small-circle" id="one"></div>
  <div class="small-circle" id="two"></div>
  <div class="small-circle" id="three"></div>
  <div class="small-circle" id="four"></div>
  <div class="small-circle" id="five"></div>
  <div class="small-circle" id="six"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone find the error please. 
I've checked other related questions already. They are not working in this case as well (I've tested).

Comment: did you try `background-image:` instead of `background:`

Comment: It works for me. Have you checked the file location of your image is correct?

Comment: yes I did. @NendoTaka ... I think it's because I'm using a **.png** as background image???

Comment: ya it works for me too, just check whether image is really in img folder and also check name and extension(i.e. png/jpeg/gif) of image

Comment: @Jack .png is fine for a background image

Comment: Just visit this its working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfn09b7f/)

Comment: file location is correct.

Comment: spell check and extension?

Comment: Try using a file on the web and if that works its a file path issue

Comment: Have you looked at the request made to the image file? Maybe you don't have permissions for the file.

Comment: it's not loading image from the directory.. But if I use an image address with `http://` , it's working fine...

Comment: again spell check and extension?

Comment: Then you have a permission or file path issue. Try moving the image to the same folder as the css file and test again.

Comment: It worked @NendoTaka , I moved the file to the same directory where the HTML file is located and it worked. Thanks... 
but I need to put the images in other directory and use them from there...???

Comment: If it works in the same directory it should work in the img directory. Check to make sure that you have the correct file path for that folder. Try adding a `/` before `img` in the file path.

Comment: that was a directory issue. this one worked fine: `url("../img/back.jpg")` ... thanks @NendoTaka

Comment: Glad you got it working. Have fun Jack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's the image located relative to the css file?

I tried your snippet and change the path of the image to an absolute URL and it worked.

Try changing your image URL to an absolute one or make sure it uses the correct path relative to the css file.

If your structure is something like this:

```
img/
    newHex.png
css/
    style.css
```

Then your correct path is

```
url('../img/newHex.png')
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: Image was first located in the other directory and the css file was in other one... I moved the image to the same directory as of HTML file and it started working...

Comment: But I need to put all images in separate directory.. any idea how do I do this?

Comment: You would have to use something like `url('../img/newHex.png')`